# Use only the numbers 0 - 2, how many 4 digits are there?

Tags: combinations

Using 4 digits to include zero, what are all the possible combinations of numbers 0, 1, and 2.  Including all the possibilities starting with zero.  like 0001, 0002, 0003, etc

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  If $4$ digits is too hard to start with, try $1$ digit.  Then $2$ digits.  And so on.

Comment: How did you make "$0003$" using "numbers $0$, $1$, and $2$"?

Comment: If you follow lulu's advice to try small examples by hand, you'll discover for yourself the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), which makes problems like this very easy.

Comment: I didn't mean to go to 0003, I just wanted to show that numbers can repeat.  And that the series could start with zero.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many such $4$-digit numbers are constructible, if the digits in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ are permitted, instead of only permitting the digits in $\{0,1,2\}$?  Further, are you familiar with **base-3** numbers?  What is the largest number that can be expressed in **base-3** with $4$ or less **base-3** digits?

Comment: appreciate the help.  thanks.  no further comments are needed.